# Changing color of form element in materialize

Tags: html, forms, material-design, materialize

**How i change the color of form input element (text, password, label ,select ,text area) Label and border-bottom.**
** i tried the style mention in materialize css documentation. But its not working.**

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l6 input-field" >
                <input type="text" name="user" id="user"  class="cng">
                <label for="user">User Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col input-field s12 m6 l6" >
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
                <label for="pass">Password</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: where is your html code?

Comment: when you say change the color of form input, do you mean text color, background, or what?

Comment: 1- Label color on focus.
2- Border-bottom color.
3-Text color of text in input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use SASS

Materialize's resources compile from .sass files, that color you are referring to can be edited from the `variablies.scss` file.

Change:

```
$secondary-color: color("red", "darken-1") !default;
```

To whatever color you wish and compile the SCSS.

Alternatively use the helper colors from [here](http://materializecss.com/color.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l6 input-field" >
                <input type="text" name="user" id="user"  class="cng">
                <label id="f-label" for="user">User Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col input-field s12 m6 l6" >
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
                <label id="s-label" for="pass">Password</label>
            </div>
```

css:

```
#user, #pass {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #yourcolor;
}

#user:focus, #pass:focus{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #yourcolor;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #yourcolor;
}


#f-label, #s-label {
        color: #yourcolor;
}
```